# Algebra logic on simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I've been self studying algebra for some time alone and a common problem I bump into that always throws me off is something like this (Complete idiots guide to algebra, if you know a better book please tell.)

simplify 5-(-3)-(+2)+(-7)

Now the double signs are removed so the non brackets become : 5+

and brackets : -3+2-7

so now you have : 5+ -3 +2 -7

now in my example it says the equation magically becomes: 5 + 3 - 2 - 7

To me this isn't logical, 
How does - 3 become 3?
Imagine if the -3 was money, where does the money come from?
How does debt suddenly become profit?
I don't even know what to call the problem I see.

I would be so grateful for someone to explain what is happening here. It is a personal hell and I can spend 3 hours looking online or ask an expert and worry about being explained to that I'm an idiot (something I'm well aware of.)

Thank you

Comment: For any $x$ [in an Abelian group, but think of $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R$], $x - y = x + (-y)$, where $-y$ is the unique additive inverse of $y$. So $x - (-y) = x + (- (- y))$. But $--y$ is the unique additive inverse of $-y$, which we know is $y$ itself. So $x - (-y) = x + y$. In particular, $5 - (-3) = 5 + 3 = 8$, which probably you knew ;/

Comment: At the very start of this equation,  say 3 -5 = 2 + (-7), that to make the equation equal you should do this 3-(-5) = 2 + (-(-7) which equals 3 - (-5) = 2 + 7, so you're passing the brackets off to the other side, however, why does 3 - 5 become 3- (- 5)? Surely the - should cancel out and become 3 as there is nothing to minus. I am missing the reasoning of x - (-y) in you're  description. (I feel I know less everyday) :)

Comment: I don't understand their approach at all ! It confuses *me*. It seems roundabout and obfuscating. Please tell me what you don't get about my comment above, at least I can clarify & justify it :D

Comment: Looking at Trold's answer, we now have the one answer I have: -3, yours at 8, and Trold's at -1. My approach was to consider the 5 as a positive bank account, then you had three businesses, two making - profit and one making + profit, if you considered this all as cash flow then you would have my answer at -3, however I have a feeling both your answer and Trold's mean that we are all looking at this question from a different perspective, I would like to know how you think this question should be approached, as cash flow, or something else?(or that I have made a mistake)

Comment: AH! I realize the problem, Trold's answer shines some light on the problem too, literally the answer should be 5+(-3) which is the same as 5+3, so (-3) = 3. Then conners answer just put the final answer in place, which is essentially what you described in your first reply, but written out would be : 5 minus -3 or 5 plus 3. Anyway thank you very much for your time. :D

Comment: Yes, 5 + -3 is 5 - 3, and 5 - -3 is 5 + 3.

Comment: @Joseph, $5+(-3)$ is $5-3$, not $5+3$. Also $(-3)$ doesn't equal $3$.

Comment: @Joseph Try to remember PEMDAS, or Parentheses then Exponents then Multiplication then Division then Addition and lastly Subtraction. Notice that Multiplication comes before Addition. The equation $5-(-3)$ can be re-written as $5$ Add $(-1)$ Times $(-3)$. You would do the multiplication first ($(-1)$ Times $(-3)$) and get positive 3 (because $(-)$ & $(-)$ $=$ $(+)$). Your equation is now $5$ Add $3$, which equals $8$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't remove the double negative signs, you replace them with a single plus sign: $5-(-3)-(+2)+(-7)$ should reduce to $5+3-2-7$, which is $-1$.  Why we should do the reduction this way isn't very intuitive, so here's an explanation should you want it.

There are two separate ideas coming together in this problem that can make it vexing.

**i)** Every number has an opposite:* $5$ has $-5$ (and likewise $-5$ has $5$). A number and its opposite added together make zero.**

**ii)** You have been lied to all your life; there is no such thing as subtraction. When we say "$5$ minus $3$" we really mean "$5$ plus the opposite of $3$", this is a mouthful, and writing $5+(-3)$ looks dumb, so it is convenient to pretend "adding the opposite of a number" is its own operation called subtraction.

So what is $5-(-3)$? Starting with (ii), we have that it's $5+(-(-3))$, or "five plus the opposite of the opposite of three." Using (i), we can say that "the opposite of the opposite of three" is three, and this leaves us with $5+(-(-3))$ being the same as $5+3$.

---

*If this seems hazy, it is. The word opposite here does have a fairly specific meaning and with sufficient explication this whole point can be subsumed into (ii), but I want to avoid taking that great a detour from your main question.

**This, paired with $0+0=0$ has the odd consequence of making zero be its own opposite, which is not usually what we think of when we say opposite, but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Think of $5-(-3)$ as $5$ minus $-3$. The $-3$ is a loss of $3$. If you take away a loss, you're getting back what you lost. In this case what you're losing is $3$, so getting that back would mean $+3$

Say you have an bank account balance of $100$ dollars and your bank charges you a $25$ dollar fee. This would be a loss of $25$ dollars, or your balance is $100-25=75$.

Now say that bank realizes they shouldn't have charged you that $25$ dollars. They would then subtract this loss from your account by giving you back the $25$ that they took. Your balance would be $75-(-25)=75+25=100$.

The two negatives cancel out to form a positive. Here's a little chart to help you remember:
$$
(+) \,\&\, (+) = (+)
$$
$$
(-) \,\&\, (-) = (+)
$$
$$
(+) \,\&\, (-) = (-)
$$
$$
(-) \,\&\, (+) = (-)
$$